# I can't the contents of my checkbox (symfony 1.0)

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have to work with Symfony 1 ( yeah I know it's pretty old ). I have to do a form where the user can enter multiple choice thanks to a checkbox. Except that when I check more than a checkbox, I only get the content of the last checkbox

I have this:

```
<tr>
    <th>Est prolongé :</th>
    <td>
        <?php echo checkbox_tag('motif', '1');  ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Est interrompu :</th>
    <td>
        <?php echo checkbox_tag('motif', '2'); ?>
    </td>
</tr>

public function executeAddFormAvenant()
{
    sfLoader::loadHelpers('Url');
    // Enregistremant d'un nouvel avenant :
    $avenant=new ConvFormAvenant();
    $avenant->setIdConvConvention($this->getRequestParameter('id_convention'));
    $conv_convention = ConvConventionPeer::retrieveByPk($this->getRequestParameter('id_convention'));
    if ($this->getRequestParameter('motif')==1)
    {
        $avenant->setEstProlongé(1);
    } else{
        $avenant->setEstProlongé(0);
    }
    if ($this->getRequestParameter('motif')==2)
    {
        $avenant->setEstInterrompu(1);
    } else{
        $avenant->setEstInterrompu(0);
    }
```

Comment: show us the `checkbox_tag` function

Comment: `function checkbox_tag($name, $value = '1', $checked = false, $options = array())
{
  $html_options = array_merge(array('type' => 'checkbox', 'name' => $name, 'id' => get_id_from_name($name, $value), 'value' => $value), _convert_options($options));
  if ($checked)
  {
    $html_options['checked'] = 'checked';
  }
  return tag('input', $html_options);`

Comment: show us also the `tag` function, because actually there you asign the `name` to the input

Comment: `function tag($name, $options = array(), $open = false)
{
  if (!$name)
  {
    return '';
  }
  return '<'.$name._tag_options($options).(($open) ? '>' : ' />');
}`

Comment: seems that you have a lot of functions, let's see `_tag_options` too

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the `checkbox_tag()` function I can only suggest changing the first parameter to `motif[]` in these lines:
`<?php echo checkbox_tag('motif', '1');  ?>`
`<?php echo checkbox_tag('motif', '2');  ?>`

The output will still be under `motif` without the brackets. If the parameter is used to name the checkboxes this would change the behaviour to an array with the values instead of only single value.

Comment: with `motif[]` I dont recover anything

Comment: Please show the definition of the ```checkbox_tag``` function.

Comment: After looking in the documentation the answer provided by myself is correct. Take a look at: http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_0/FormHelper#method_checkbox_tag

Comment: I did this `<?php echo checkbox_tag('motif[]','1'); ?>` but that change nothing, I dont recover anything. I checked 2 checkbox but nothing happens. It does not even fit in the if

Comment: What doesn't fit in the if? The if statements should remain untouched.

Comment: For exemple if I check 2 checkbox, It does no fit in the if, it does not fit in a the 2 condition `if ($this->getRequestParameter('motif')==1)
    {
        $avenant->setEstProlongé(1);
    } else{
        $avenant->setEstProlongé(0);
    }
    if ($this->getRequestParameter('motif')==2)
    {
        $avenant->setEstInterrompu(1);
    } else
        $avenant->setEstInterrompu(0);
    }` and I dont know why. It works with only 1 checkbox.

Comment: side note: don't use `setEstProlongé` use the english char to code `setEstProlonge` or `setEstProlongee` or something that fits. And the code itself should be in english too.